# linux searching multiple files with same prefix and sending only file names in an email

Tags: linux

we r using korn shell.. the req is 2 informatica jobs create 4 files with tstamp( each infa job creates 2 files) so lets say file names 1.ttmm_rels_prspt.ctl_tstamp 2.ttmm_rels_prspt.lsf_tstamp 3. ttmm_rels_rfc.ctl_tstamp 4. ttmm_rels_rfc.scf_tstamp.. so files create in the following path opt/etl/tgtfiles . ttmm_rels is the common prefix for 4 files.. if 4 files created on the server we hav to send an email sayin success with files names. and files should rename to procesd_filename. so the next day we wont get same files on the server since we renamed to processed. if 1 infa job fails there wil b only 2 files on the server. so send an success email with 2 file names and rename to processd for those 2 files also for other 2 files send delay email(if one infa job fails total 2 emails we send) on re-run of infa job again we have to send success email and rename the file names to processd_filename

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `bash`:

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=( ttmm_rels* )

if [[ -n "$files" ]]; then
  msg="$(printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}")"
  subj="Success"
else
  msg="Sorry, no files yet"
  subj="Delay"
fi

printf '%s\n' "$msg" | mail -s "$subj" pooh.bear@100.acre.wood
```

For `ksh93`, which doesn't have the `nullglob` shell option, you will have to test whether the globbing pattern matched anything:

```
files=( ttmm_rels* )

if [[ "${#files}" == 1 && "$files" == "tmm_rels*" && ! -f "ttmm_rels*" ]]; then
  msg="Sorry, no files yet"
  subj="Delay"
else
  msg="$(printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}")"
  subj="Success"
fi

printf '%s\n' "$msg" | mail -s "$subj" pooh.bear@100.acre.wood
```

Comment: hi Kusalananda thanks for your reply... I am actually trying through korn shell.. will it work  for korn shell please reply me back.

Comment: @vani `ksh93`-version added.

Comment: hi Kusalananda we r using korn shell.. the req is 2 informatica jobs create 4 files with tstamp( each infa job creates 2 files) so lets say file names 1.ttmm_rels_prspt.ctl_tstamp 2.ttmm_rels_prspt.lsf_tstamp 3. ttmm_rels_rfc.ctl_tstamp 4. ttmm_rels_rfc.scf_tstamp.. so files create in the following path  opt/etl/tgtfiles . ttmm_rels is the common prefix for 4 files.. if 4 files created on the server we hav to send an email sayin success with files names. and files should rename to procesd_filename. if 1 infa job fails send 2 file names in an success email 2 file names in delay email.

Comment: if we rename to processd_filename it will not fetch same files next day.. so 1 job fails there wil b only 2 files on the server and for them we have to send an "success" email (rename thm to process_file name after sending email) and for remaing 2 files send an "delay" email. and when we re-run the second infa job it wil create 2 files send an success email and rename to process_filenmae.    I hope this is very clear now.. I am new to scripting please help me :(

Comment: @vani Please update the text in the question with all relevant information needed to solve your problem.

Comment: I added in the comment.. can you please check

Comment: I added in the question too.. @kusalananda